# 'npm run deploy' not working for 'gh-pages'

Tags: javascript, github, npm, github-pages, npm-run

##### I'm trying to deploy static `react.js` website on `github` using `gh-pages`

> 1. Downloaded git and github successfully.
> 2. Completed All previous steps mentioned at [CRA deployment using Github Pages](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) successfully.
> 3. Committed all changes to the repo.

But I'm stuck at the last command `npm run deploy`.

##### Error looks like this:

[image]

I saw other similar questions on stack overflow, but none matched mine.

Answer (score 0):

**try to first off all increase the git long paths to true and then try again** use this command in console

`git config --system core.longpaths true`

Comment: I tried that earlier, it didn't work

Comment: @HIMANSHUPANDEY did you start git bash as administrator?

Comment: I didn't use git-bash, as it wasn't required in the steps mentioned in that CRA development link

Comment: can you show the file names of all the files also any terminal you use for that command but make sure to use it as administrator @HIMANSHUPANDEY

Comment: Well, that administrator part worked for me, the command ran, and GitHub started the deploying process, but now it looks like some other error has occurred.. GitHub says.... 'The job running on runner Hosted Agent has exceeded the maximum execution time of 360 minutes' and 'docker pull failed with exit code 1'.